# Failed to initialize Firebase app instance from an isolate

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-isolates

I am trying to interact with the Firestore from a separate isolate. So far I am stacked on Firebase app initialization inside the isolate.

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Firebase app initialized in the main isolate");
  ActivityReportHandler.instance.trackActivity();
}
```

**activity_report_handler.dart**

```
void trackActivityInBackground(message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Firebase app initialized in an isolate");
}
```

top-level function

While trying to initialize the FirebaseApp instance inside the isolate I get an exception
`Unhandled Exception: Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`

If I add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` on the first line of `trackActivityInBackground`, I get an exception:
`UI actions are only available on root isolate.`

Under the hood, when `await Firebase.initializeApp()` is called, after a series of calls finally the app tries to get `binaryMessenger`, but when I dived deeper, I've noticed that both `_binaryMessenger` and `ServiceBinding.instance` are null here

```
BinaryMessenger get binaryMessenger => _binaryMessenger ?? ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger;
```

So the source of the crash is clear, what is not clear, is how to make it work? :D

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: "Please check this [Github thread](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3124) about the same issue. Does it answer your question? "

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty before asking I read it, but was not attentive enough. Just have read it again and yes, it answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In refernce to this question the following [github thread](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3124) answers this question.